# Marker moves itself vertically in LeafletJS with Google Maps Satellite (Birds Eye)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, leaflet

Check out a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VudEC/3/

It's about using Google's Satellite Layer (in example: zoom=20), **birds eye mode enabled** and a marker.

```
var map = new L.Map('map_canvas', {
    center: new L.LatLng(39.868841, -4.021938),
    zoom: 20
});

var ggl = new L.Google('SATELLITE');
map.addLayer(ggl);

var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(39.868841, -4.021938));
map.addLayer(marker);
```

If you drag vertically the map (or use the function map.panBy()) you will see the marker moving up or down (vertically). And it shouldn't.

If the drag or movement is horizontal, no problem.

If I disabled the birds eye (or set a lower zoom), the issue disappear.

At least it happens with polygons too.

Btw, with Google Maps API it doesn't happen: http://jsfiddle.net/ew332/1/

I don't understand why I get this issue. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's a bug of the plugin, you can read more [here](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/issues/111) and for now, there is no a fix